# How to create object variables so that new pointers are allocated every time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, pointers, graphics

this is my first question here on Stackoverflow. I'm creating a paint program on GP142 using C++ and I'm having trouble recreating the canvas.
When the program is loaded, it asks for points (or vertex containing x and y) and creates a shape (which is a class) by joining all those points. I'm saving the points in a point* vector:

```
vector<shape*> arr;
```

When a shape is completed, it is supposed to be saved in the vector array. I'm saving it using:

```
line l(points,2); //2 is num of points
l.draw();
arr.push_back(&l);
```

There are 5 different shape types, and all are created within a while(true) loop which terminates on menu selections. On selection of **undo** from menu, the shape created last is to be deleted.
I'm deleting it using:

```
if (arr.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0;i < arr.size() - 1;i++) {
        arr[i]->draw();
    }
    arr.pop_back();
}
```

When I do undo, it deletes all the shapes with same type. Like it deletes all the **Lines** I created. Is there any method I could differentiate all the **Lines** and other variables so they could be deleted explicitly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems. First, you are creating the `line`s in a while loop so when the loop finishes and your lines go out of scope all the pointers in your vector will be dangling pointers, i.e. will be pointing to `line`s that have been destroyed. You can avoid this problem by using `std::unique_ptr`s or `std::shared_ptr`s depending on your requirements. Assuming you go for shared_ptrs then the type of your vector should be `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<shape>>` and in the loop you would have

```
auto a_line = std::make_shared<line>(points,2); //2 is num of points
a_line->draw();
arr.push_back(a_line);
```

Second, to remove the last element of the vector all you need to do is `arr.pop_back()` provided the array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last element of the vector `arr`:

```
if (!arr.empty())
    arr.pop_back();
```

Comment: if (arr.size() > 0)
actually means the same